# Why I can't enter to my main folder of project which contains code after pushing to GitHub from VS Code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, push, pull

In the picture, left of **sign-me-up** folder it shows an arrow sign on the folder icon. And I can't go inside the folder. Why so and what to do ?

[image: Screenshot]

I created a git repo last month and pushed the code to **main** branch. Today I push the full project in **master** branch and create a pull request and merged to **main** branch. After merging this problem occurs.

I'm trying to entering the folder as like other folders are working but not able to enter.

Comment: why do you have a `main` branch and a `master` branch

Comment: actually I made some changes to try something new.... after successfully compiling I just merged these two... main and master and delete one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow folder icon indicates that this folder is a symbolic link.

If you cannot enter it, the link is broken and points to an invalid location.

You can check the link target in your local clone:

```
readlink sign-me-up
```

Make sure that the output is a valid *relative* path within your repository.

Comment: @PURNENDUBIKASHJANA If it helped, please [vote up my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: yeah of course ... but my reputation is below 15 so :(

Comment: @PURNENDUBIKASHJANA you can still accept the answer by clicking on the check button next to it whenever you think it resolved your problem.

Comment: yeah.... i did it... thank you